# Class Representation of Half Adder Circuit

Tags: python, class

I'm working through [this book](https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Introduction/ObjectOrientedProgramminginPythonDefiningClasses.html#inheritance-logic-gates-and-circuits) and am trying to extend its code to make a half adder and eventually a full adder.

I think I should be implementing a way to return the carry and bits from the half adder separately to facilitate connection to later gates. However, that's where I'm blanking. I also need some way to call `performGateLogic` on the `HalfAdder` and 'pipe' the inputs to both the `XorGate` and `AndGate` and have tried so with `Connector`s. My brain is just being tied in a pretzel over the method calling and class relations here and I'd appreciate someone straightening it out.

```
class LogicGate:

def __init__(self,n):
    self.name = n
    self.output = None

def getName(self):
    return self.name

def getOutput(self):
    self.output = self.performGateLogic()
    return self.output


class BinaryGate(LogicGate):

def __init__(self,n):
    LogicGate.__init__(self,n)

    self.pinA = None
    self.pinB = None

def getPinA(self):
    if self.pinA == None:
        return int(input("Enter Pin A input for gate "+self.getName()+"-->"))
    else:
        return self.pinA.getFrom().getOutput()

def getPinB(self):
    if self.pinB == None:
        return int(input("Enter Pin B input for gate "+self.getName()+"-->"))
    else:
        return self.pinB.getFrom().getOutput()

def setNextPin(self,source):
    if self.pinA == None:
        self.pinA = source
    else:
        if self.pinB == None:
            self.pinB = source
        else:
            print("Cannot Connect: NO EMPTY PINS on this gate")


class AndGate(BinaryGate):

def __init__(self,n):
    BinaryGate.__init__(self,n)

def performGateLogic(self):

    a = self.getPinA()
    b = self.getPinB()
    if a==1 and b==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

class XorGate(BinaryGate):

def __init__(self,n):
    BinaryGate.__init__(self,n)

def performGateLogic(self):

    a = self.getPinA()
    b = self.getPinB()
    if (a ==1 and b==0) or (a==0 and b==1):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

class Connector:

def __init__(self, fgate, tgate):
    self.fromgate = fgate
    self.togate = tgate

    tgate.setNextPin(self)

def getFrom(self):
    return self.fromgate

def getTo(self):
    return self.togate

class HalfAdder(BinaryGate):

def __init__(self,n):
    BinaryGate.__init__(self,n)

    self.bits, self.carry = None, None
    self.a, self.b = None, None
    self.xor = XorGate('XO')
    self.and_ = AndGate('A')
    self.c1 = Connector(self.xor.getPinA(), self.and_.getPinA())
    self.c2 = Connector(self.xor.getPinB(), self.and_.getPinB())

def performGateLogic(self):

    self.a = self.getPinA()
    self.b = self.getPinB()

    self.bits = 1 if (self.a ==1 and self.b==0) or (self.a==0 and self.b==1) else 0
    self.carry = 1 if (self.a==1 and self.b ==1) else 0
    return self.bits + self.carry
```

Running `print(HalfAdder('HA').getOutput())` yields

```
File "./circuits.py", line 178, in __init__
    self.c1 = Connector(self.xor.getPinA(), self.and_.getPinA())
  File "./circuits.py", line 161, in __init__
tgate.setNextPin(self)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'setNextPin'
```

Something is being set to an `int` but where, I can't find.

Comment: `.getPinA()` returns an int.  It's not something that can be meaningfully passed to `Connector()`, I think you want the `.pinA` attribute instead.

Comment: Good spot, however `XorGate` has no `.pinA` attribute. Turns out `Connector` arguments should be whole class objects and not class methods or properties.